# Angular2 filter nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I have an array of objects as below. I am trying to achieve search functionality using .filter() method in my angular2 application.

```
[{
"label": "new",
"result": [{
    "label": "new",
    "fname": "abc",
    "lname": "xyz"
}, {
    "label": "new",
    "fname": "abc1",
    "lname": "xyz1"
}]},
{
    "label": "old",
    "result": [{
        "label": "old",
        "fname": "abc2",
        "lname": "xyz2"
    }]
}]
```

I am able to achieve parent/one level filtering using below code:

```
this.data.filter(item => (item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputText) !== -1);
```

This is returning the object that matches value of label. I want to have filter on 'fname' and 'lname' also.

Comment: Have you got any luck on this one yet? I am looking for the solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is not well suited for doing an arbitrary string lookup from a 3 level data structure like this.

Your are going to end up having to iterate all three levels - the array of objects, the results array in each object, and all the properties of the objects in the results array.

This is an O(n^3) operation and would likely perform unsatisfactorily with a large data set.  You may need to think about how you can better structure this data for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would when I get the data from the server create a lookup variable inside every item which contains all text you want to be able to search.

But make sure this is only done once, since it's wouldn't be very performant if you did it for every keystroke.

```
// Add searchable string to users
  users.forEach(u => {
    u.filterTerm = `${(u.id || '').toLowerCase()} ${(u.email || '').toLowerCase()} ${(u.firstName || '').toLowerCase()} ${(u.lastName || '').toLowerCase()}`;
});
```

Then you can use the includes method to filter

```
let filtered = allUsers.filter(u => {
  return u.filterTerm.includes(filterTerm);
});
```